# Unable to Deploy Diaspora on Heroku remote rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, deployment, diaspora

I am trying to deploy diaspora on heroku by following all the steps here https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/Installation/Heroku but at the end when i am deploying diaspora it give error as

```
 ahmed@ahmed-desktop:~/diaspora$ git push -u heroku heroku:master
Counting objects: 132081, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (29619/29619), done.
Writing objects: 100% (132081/132081), 91.87 MiB | 59.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 132081 (delta 101146), reused 132070 (delta 101138)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: Build stream timed out, reverting to polling....
remote: -----> Deleting 6 files matching .slugignore patterns.
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: 
remote: !   Timeout reached polling for results.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/hellohi.git
 ! [remote rejected] heroku -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hellohi.git'
```

any help...

Comment: Might be a simple timeout issue, did you try it multiple times?

Comment: more then 5 times @Jonne Haß i had also used your video https://asciinema.org/a/2248 but nothing happend...please sir help me

Comment: and i had not done any change in the diaspora.yml.example file @JonneHaß

Comment: and @JonneHaß i think am doing something wrong at
`heroku config:add SECRET_TOKEN=$(curl -s "http://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=40&format=h" | tr -d " \n")`

because i get this as a result of it

`Setting config vars and restarting samiraa... done, v7
SECRET_TOKEN: <!DOCTYPEHTMLPUBLIC"-//IETF//DTDHTML2.0//EN"><html><head><title>301MovedPermanently</title></head><body><h1>MovedPermanently</h1><p>Thedocumenthasmoved<ahref="https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=40&amp;format=h">here</a>.</p><hr><address>Apache/2.2.22(Debian)Serveratwww.random.orgPort80</address></body></html>`